# how to evaluate firestore query before executing the next lline

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that should return a list of documents data from a given collection.

```
function _getPrevActivity(){

let historyCollectionRef =  firestore.collection("/users/RSgNDLPxT2aAERQutXEEyhHHJYk1/agreements/DkRdZ5kHi2g7MlBV3Kjq/test/test-something/records/15/history");
let value = [];
let wait;
    historyCollectionRef.orderBy('timeStamp').onSnapshot(querSnap => {
    querSnap.forEach(doc => {
        value.push(doc.data())
        console.log(value.length, " length")

        })
    console.log(value)
    return value;

    });

return value;
```

}

This functions is always returning `[]` and later executing the firestore query.

PS: I am new to Node env, there might be something wrong with how I wrote the function as well.

Comment: `onSnapshot` returns immediately, which means your function will return `value` unchanged from its original value.  The callback you pass on `onSnapshot` will be invoked some time later, when the results of the query is ready.  In other words, you can't just make a function return a value produced asynchronously.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Also bear in mind that the callback to onSnapshot will be invoked possibly many times, once for each change to the document.  If you want just one value, use `get()` instead.

Comment: Well thats just sad, so there is no way to achieve this without changing firestore api ? I have changed `onSnapshot` to `get`.

Comment: Asynchronous programming with promises (like the ones returned by `get()`) is extremely common in javascript and node.  You really can't avoid it.  https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93

Comment: Well it makes sense after reading through the article, just need to refactor on my end

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the classic mistake of handling asynchronous calls like you do with synchronous programming.

I restructured your code as follows:

```
function _getPrevActivity() {
      let value = [];
      let wait;
      const path = "/users/RSgNDLPxT2aAERQutXEEyhHHJYk1/agreements/DkRdZ5kHi2g7MlBV3Kjq/test/test-something/records/15/history";

      return firestore.collection(path).orderBy('timeStamp')
        .onSnapshot(querSnap => {
          querSnap.forEach(doc => {
            value.push(doc.data())
            console.log(value.length, " length")
          });
          console.log(value)
          return value;
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          return value;
        });
    }

    // calling function
    function otherFunc() {
      _getPrevActivity().then(value => {
        // do something with value...
        // value will not be an empty array now
        console.log(value);
      }).catch(console.log);
    }
```

The mistake you are doing here is that you can't really return a value from the anonymous function `querSnap => {...` unless you also return the enclosing promise from the function from which you want the value returned.

Also, to access the value from the `return` of an async call will require the use of the `then()` clause which I have added to the code below.

Comment: I tried this but in `otherFunc` is throwing error, `_getPrevActivity)(...).then is not a function`

Comment: Are you using the correct syntax? It is `_getPrevActivity().then(value)` and not `_getPrevActivity)(...).then` what you wrote here in the comment.